# Не знаю как решить задачу с дробями на Python

Tags: python

Вот условие задачи:

Коля учится в третьем классе, сейчас они проходят простые дроби с натуральными числителем и знаменателем. Вчера на уроке Коля узнал, что дробь называется правильной, если ее числитель меньше знаменателя, и несократимой, если нет равной ей дроби с меньшими натуральными числителем и знаменателем.

Коля очень любит математику, поэтому дома он долго экспериментировал, придумывая и решая разные задачки с правильными несократимыми дробями. Одну из этих задач Коля предлагает решить вам с помощью компьютера.

Найдите наибольшую правильную несократимую дробь, у которой сумма числителя и знаменателя равна n.

Входные данные
Во входном файле записано одно целое число n (3n1000).

Выходные данные
Выведите в выходной файл числитель и знаменатель искомой дроби.

Мой код:

```
def nod(a,b):
    while b!=0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
n=int(input())
a=0
b=n-a
for i in range(n):
    while a//nod(a,b)!= 1 and b//nod(a,b) !=1:
        a,b = a-1 , b+1
print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если чуть-чуть покумекать, то всё упростится:

```
a=n//2
b=n-a
while nod(a,b)!= 1:
    a-=1
    b+=1
```